# How do I correctly pass, as argument, a literal integer as a void pointer, using its address as the integer’s actual value

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

As an experiment:

I have hypothetical function with signature: `void func(void *)`, where I have to pass an integer value, literally in the code: `func(42)`. *It must be done with a literal integer*.

Is there a “right” way to pass a integer value, say, “hacked” as an address in a pointer (to address 0x2A for example), and the somehow convert it back to an integer (42 for the 0x2A example). All of this without unexpected behavior?

In short: being able to convert a pointer address into an integer which will hold the number of the address.

Comment: I don't think you can pass a pointer to a literal. It will also be a constant one. Why not int* a = 42, func(a)?

Comment: There's no way to pass a pointer to a literal. It makes no sense. You have to rethink why you need to do this.

Comment: What does this literal number represent?  Is it the (virtual?) memory address of some useful data?  "It must be done with a literal integer." Why?  "I have a function with signature `void func(void*)`" What does it do and what does it expect the `void *` to represent?

Comment: @john I did not ask how to pass a pointer to a literal.

Comment: @BrianCain it is not the address of anything, I just want to pass an integer to a function that expects a void pointer, without having to assign the integer to a variable first. Why? Just because I want to, I am experimenting. The void* isn’t expected to represent anything particularly, it is just an hypothetical case where an API forces me to use that argument type and I want to send an integer typed literally in the code.

Comment: Note that `0x42` is **not** an address; it's simply a hexadecimal literal with the decimal value 66.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are right, it is 0x2A actually.

Comment: @Alec - yes, it is, indeed 0x2A, for some unspecified value of "it".

Comment: @PeteBecker I want to actually use the address as the integer value. I read that it is possible with a `intptr_t`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight told you how to do that, and you told him to shove off.

Comment: No @PeteBecker, he does not address how to convert the address back to an integer.

Comment: Stop vandalizing this question, please.  Based on the meta discussion, I still believe it can be saved, but trashing your stuff isn't really okay.

Comment: @Mario You don't own the copyright to this post; user contributions are licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  However, I've reverted to the last-non-defaced version, and asked for a mod to lock it.

Comment: Sure, lets lock it, sure locked it will be any more useful to anybody else. This site is full of content nazis that will refuse to delete anything only for the sake of refusing.

Comment: @Mario Godwin's law, eh?  Either way; you're the one unwilling to try and fix your question; and lets face it; it is only you who can fix your question, as only you know what it is you want help with.

Comment: I don't want help with anything since it was only an experiment to begin with, which I am not interested in anymore. You are not the only one believing to know what is inside my mind also.
Whatever, after noticing how I no longer own what I author for this site I am getting my account deleted now. So bye, I will contribute somewhere else than Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Mario That's a rather extreme response, and I never stated I knew your thoughts, rather the opposite; if the question could be improved, only you can improve it, because only you know what you were attempting to ask.  But owning the material shouldn't be a deciding factor.. the goal of this site is to create a learning resource for all, after all.

Comment: I kept being told that I can "fix" something that I won't "fix". If you all so want to keep a question in the site then you go fix it. I just submitted my account deletion request.

Comment: @Mario That's not the point I'm trying to convey; only you can fix it, because only you know what you were trying to ask.  We aren't mind readers, we can't fix it.  I get that you're unwilling to fix it, though; which is a shame.  As stated, the goal is a learning resource for everyone; it shouldn't matter that we don't own our contributions.

Comment: I won't fix it, period. Now get it locked and enjoy a perpetually useless question.

Comment: @Mario Since you're not going to deface it anymore, the lock shouldn't be required.  As to the 'usefulness' of the question, that is determined by how well the answers below help people, and it does appear that at least three were helped.

Comment: At least three were helped because... some commented? or someone upvoted? strange your logic to say at least.

Comment: @Mario Three were helped because there are three upvotes, total, on the answers.  I'm not going to re-iterate the tooltip text of the upvote button, but fine; you want to quit SO because nothing truly belongs to you.  A shame, a waste; if you're in it for yourself, you're in it for the wrong reasons.  Either way, I'm done.

Comment: Upvotes that don't reply what I asked for might be useful, for anything else than what I asked.

Comment: @Mario Useful to you, no, but that can't be helped given you're not going to improve the question.  Useful to others however.. yes, since that's the goal of this site; to build a knowledge base.

Answer (score 5):

Both C and C++ standards explicitly allow for such conversion.

C99 6.3.2.3.5:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

C++11 5.2.10.5

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer.

Therefore, your call of `func((void*)42)` should work with all standard-compliant compilers.

> What is the, say, most correct way to pass a literal integer to an argument expecting a void pointer, and having the integer untouched in the function?

This way of passing a literal integer as an argument to a function expecting a `void*` guarantees that the original integer would be untouched in the function, because the argument is passed by value.

Comment: ding, ding, ding!  OP has worded it poorly, but you have decoded his question and provided the right answer.

Comment: @Alec I think you should lose the attitude, remember people are trying to help, even though your requirements aren't very clear.

Comment: ding, ding, ding! No Brian, this answer does not address what I asked for. Seeing how the previous questions all tried to answer exactly what I asked for, I can only conclude the reading understanding issue is yours.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be done this way.

You can allocate the value on the stack and then call the function.

Example in C:

```
int i = 42;
func((void*) (&i));
```

Example in C++:

```
int i = 42;
func(reinterpret_cast<void*> (&i));
```

Otherwise, if you are not sure about the life time of the variable, it can be allocated on the heap using *malloc()/free()* or *new/delete*.

Comment: What do you think of passing a pointer to address 0x42 and somehow converting it to an integer?

Comment: No cast is needed in either language. Every object address converts implicitly to `void*`.